# Sending email from my domain vs from the admin google account?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have a domain xyz.com and right now it is pointing to my app in appspot. I want to send email alerts to users for various events. However, appengine restricts email sender to admin email address which was used to create the google app engine account.

Can I send emails on behalf of user@xyz.com using app engine? If not, is there a simple workaround to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation about [sending mail](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Sending_Mail) from within Google App Engine, the email sender has to be either:

- the email address of an admin account associated with the application OR
- the Google Account email address of the current signed-in user OR
- a valid app email address (*string* @ *appid*.appspotmail.com, see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Receiving_Mail) for more info)

So if your user is logged in with his/her Google Account while using the app, you will be able to send the mail with sender user@xyz.com.
If not, you will have to use an admin account's email, an app email address or create a separate Google Account (which you make an admin of the app) to use for this purpose as is suggested as a workaround in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Sending_Mail).

Answer (score 2):

When sending email, you can designate the sender as either the currently logged in user or any registered administrator. It does not have to be the administrator who created the app.

Also note that you can add any email address as an administrator on your app (from the permissions tab in the admin console). It does not need to be a Gmail or Google Apps account; any email account that you can access to click on the confirmation link will work.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right that you can use any e-mail address.  But if it isn't already tied to a Google account, then you have to [sign up for a Google account](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) with that e-mail address in order to be able to sign-in and accept the request to be an administrator on the app.