# GAE Send mail - > How to replace mail@myapp.appspotmail.com to mail@mydomain.com

Tags: python, google-app-engine

According documentation Google App Engine could send mail but from restricted list of addresses -> http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html

How to send email from Google App Engine with "from:" of custom domain i.e. mydomain.com?

Is it need configuration or use of custom library - please help with your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender address must be a verfied dev, owner or viewer of the app or a logged in google user. I can send emails from admin@mycustomdomain.net after adding that email address to permissions. You can also send an email from the logged in user if the user is logged in with a google account.

I hope this explains some of what you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to send it as long as the email id is registered as an administrator of the App Engine app. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292238/sending-email-from-my-domain-vs-from-the-admin-google-account) for more info.

Comment: @Nicke Yes. Must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by Google Apps

Comment: I found one problem that I have account in Google Apps called xxx@xxx.com and alias alias@xxx.com and during registration of alias@xxx.com GAE register not alias@xxx.com but xxx@xxx.com the question is if it will works xxx@xxx.com and alias@xxx.com or only xxx@xxx.com?